# How to design my repositories when there are multiple sources for the same sort of data?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository

In my application, I have to get data from our ERP. For this example, let's say product data.

Some of the data will come from the API that our ERP has provided us, whilst some of it will come from direct DB calls as the API doesn't give us all the required detail.

For this situation, do I just do with a single Repository and within the repository methods I get the data from the required place?

If I do this, my concern is that I will be injecting into the constructor IApiService as well as database connection strings which depending on the data I am retrieving, it may not be necessary.

Do I create 2 separate repository, something like ApiProductRepository and DatabaseProductRepository?

Some guidance on the best methods here would be great!

Answer (score 3):

I would create two separate implementations of the repository interface like `ApiProductRepository` and `DatabaseProductRepository`. Each implementation will throw an `NotSupportedException` for methods that it doesn't support. Finally create a `ErpRepository` that takes an `ApiProductRepository` and `DatabaseProductRepository` and invokes the appropriate implementation based on the method.

Here is a class diagram describing how I would design the solution

[image]

**Edit:** I was answering under the assumption that some *methods* would be provided by the DB and some by the API. After OP clarified that some *attributes* of the model will be filled from the API and some will be filled by the DB, the design above doesn't cover that case well, and I would use the simpler design:

[image]

Comment: I like it! Will implement and see how I go

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: +1 for using PlantUML. So great tool. However, the last composition (IMO) is unnecessary. Isn't it?

Comment: @Laiv: IMHO< the composition is useful to hide for higher-level clients the fact that the Product information is coming from multiple sources.

Comment: Is there any benefit that DbProductRepository and ApiProductRepository both inherit from the interface ProductRepository? For me DbProductRepository and ApiProductRepository are just implementation details of ErpProductRepository

Comment: My concern is if Db and API repositories can accomplish completely with the interface.`Some of the data will come from the API that our ERP has provided us, whilst some of it will come from direct DB calls as the API doesn't give us all the required detail.`

Comment: @Laiv they will both be partial implementations of the interface. I think the tests will be better, and each impl will be less complex. Each has fewer responsibilities and dependencies. And it leaves room to add more method impls to either.

Comment: I think the idea is good. But implementing half interface doesn't looks good to me. Anyways, nothing important. Adapters where made for something :-)

Comment: With this method, where would I "merge" the separate result sets? From what I've read, it is best if the repository returns the business objects. My example is that I get the product listing from the ERP's API, but I some attributes from the database directly (the API doesn't support getting these attributes). Would these be joined in the ErpRepository?

Comment: @Lock I misinterpreted your question then. I thought you were fetching *all* attributes for different methods from either the DB or the API, not some attributes from both. If that's the case I would just implement `ErpProductRepository` that implements all the logic for fetching and merging attributes.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel. So I would pass in a connectionString as well as a IApiService so I can get data from both sources and merge. Does this sound OK?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm suggesting. I would pass a connection or data source itself (I'm not that familiar with C#) instead of a connection string because `ErpProductRepository` shouldn't be responsible for connecting the to the database, and you may want some pooling strategy with db connections that should be configured outside of this class.